# Partition Program in embedded C

Tags: c, partition

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Partition boot sector at LBA = 1
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Physical Sector - 1, Logical Sector - 0.  
//This is the first sector in the partition, and is known as the "volume boot record" or "partition boot sector"
//Note: This table is filesystem specific.  Re-formatting the drive will overwrite this table.  
const uint8_t PARTITION_ATTRIBUTES(BOOT_SECTOR_ADDRESS) BootSector[FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE]  BOOT_SEC_ADDR_TAG =
{
0xEB, 0x3C, 0x90,           //Jump instruction
'M', 'S', 'D', 'O', 'S', '5', '.', '0', //OEM Name "MSDOS5.0"
(FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE&0xFF), (FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE>>8),       //Bytes per sector (FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE)
0x01,               //Sectors per cluster
DRV_FILEIO_INTERNAL_FLASH_NUM_RESERVED_SECTORS, 0x00,           //Reserved sector count (usually 1 for FAT12 or FAT16)
0x01,               //number of FATs 
DRV_FILEIO_CONFIG_INTERNAL_FLASH_MAX_NUM_FILES_IN_ROOT, 0x00,           //Max number of root directory entries - 16 files allowed
0x00, 0x00,         //total sectors (0x0000 means: use the 4 byte field at offset 0x20 instead)
0xF8,               //Media Descriptor
DRV_FILEIO_INTERNAL_FLASH_NUM_FAT_SECTORS, 0x00,         //Sectors per FAT
0x3F, 0x00,                 //Sectors per track
0xFF, 0x00,                 //Number of heads
0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,     //Hidden sectors
(uint8_t)DRV_FILEIO_INTERNAL_FLASH_PARTITION_SIZE, (uint8_t)(DRV_FILEIO_INTERNAL_FLASH_PARTITION_SIZE >> 8), (uint8_t)(DRV_FILEIO_INTERNAL_FLASH_PARTITION_SIZE >> 16), (uint8_t)(DRV_FILEIO_INTERNAL_FLASH_PARTITION_SIZE >> 24),  //Total sectors (when WORD value at offset 20 is 0x0000)

0x00,           //Physical drive number
0x00,           //Reserved("current head")
0x29,           //Signature
0x32, 0x67, 0x94, 0xC4,     //ID(serial number)
'N', 'O', ' ', 'N', 'A', 'M', 'E', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',  //Volume Label (11 bytes) - "NO NAME    "
'F', 'A', 'T', '1', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', //FAT system "FAT12   "
//Operating system boot code
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x55, 0xAA          //End of sector (0x55AA)
};
```

I am trying to use part of the program memory of my dspic33 controller as mass storage device. I am using a reference program to understand what happens inside of the program. When I go through it, I find this section. Actually I don't know it's syntax and it seems new to me. I want to understand about this section. If anybody come across these type of programs in c, kindly explain it.

Comment: That's just data.

Comment: @Mat, Actually I want to know the syntax of that section start from 'const' key word

Comment: What *part* of "the syntax"? It all looks standard C to me. It's just a very, very long list of unsigned character values – in a variety of notations, but still. `0xXX`, for example, is hex notation.

Comment: "const uint8_t PARTITION_ATTRIBUTES(BOOT_SECTOR_ADDRESS) BootSector[FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE]  BOOT_SEC_ADDR_TAG =
{ 
 //End of sector (0x55AA) }". I am asking about this section covered under double quotes. I couldn't find it's syntax.

Comment: You need to lookup the `#define`s of al those capital parts, which I assume are macros.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, Yeah it is macros.                                                               
                                                                                                                  
 #define PARTITION_ATTRIBUTES(sector_num)    __attribute__((space(psv), address(DRV_FILEIO_INTERNAL_FLASH_CONFIG_FILES_ADDRESS + (sector_num * FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE))))                                             But the thing is, I cannot correlate this macro and the syntax of that function

Answer (score 1):

It seems to contain the first block of the physical drive.

When your system boots up, it loads the first block of the physical disk into a pre-determined place in memory (pre-determined by the BIOS) and then transfers control to this block. There it encounters a jump instruction and jumps there. The jump instruction has been hard-coded and may need to know where the BIOS loaded the block. I did not decode the jump instruction but was expecting it to jump into the section called "operating system boot code" but that section contains only nulls.

Following this jump instruction are what seems the data of a FAT12 filesystem.

Without more information it is difficult to say more about it. So it could be a boot block that is written physically to block 0 of the drive, but it seems to require the boot code. To some part it depends on the detailed definition of the boot block and FAT12 filesystem, and on the BIOS code of the actual machine reading this into memory.

So, though not a definitive and complete explanation, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you determine the snippet is from the block of the physical drive? Is this a prototype for writing block of the physical drive? If yes, can you explain it?

Comment: I have been working on boot blocks so I recognized the method. I just explained it, but I would need more of the code to be more precise. On Linux there is for example the utility `mkfs` (Make file system) that contains the logic of assembling the boot block, for the particular hardware and BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

In `const uint8_t PARTITION_ATTRIBUTES(BOOT_SECTOR_ADDRESS) BootSector[FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE]  BOOT_SEC_ADDR_TAG =
{ … };`:

- `const` says the elements of the array being defined will not be modified after the arary is created.
- `uint8_t` says the elements of the array being defined are 8-bit unsigned integers.
- `PARTITION_ATTRIBUTES(BOOT_SECTOR_ADDRESS)` is likely a preprocessor macro defined in some header that may contain some compiler-specific keywords for describing attributes of the object being declared. (This hypothesis is based on the contents of the text and on experience, not on strict requirements of the C language.)
- `BootSector` is the name of the array being defined.
- `[FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE]` says the array contains `FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE` elements, where `FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE` is likely a preprocessor macro defined in some header.
- `BOOT_SEC_ADDR_TAG` is likely some preprocessor macro containing compiler-specific keywords, as above.
- `= { … }` provides the data used to initialize the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can understand all of it but separately as you explained in the answer. But I want to know, how this syntax is formed? Is it there in C?

Comment: @CNA: `const uint8_t MyArray[Size] = { initial values };` is standard C. `uint8_t` is declared in the standard header `<stdint.h>`. The attributes and tag are extra, probably not strictly conforming standard C, and we would need to see the preprocessor macro definitions to provide more information on them.

Comment: Here are macro definitions:                                                                                       "#define PARTITION_ATTRIBUTES(sector_num)    __attribute__((space(psv), address(DRV_FILEIO_INTERNAL_FLASH_CONFIG_FILES_ADDRESS + (sector_num * FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE)))) "                                                                                              "#define BOOT_SECTOR_ADDRESS         1"